# 'isValid' is always false

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I am using custom `register` in `react-hook-form`, and I am unable to get `formState.isValid` to be `true` when I enter text into the input (and so satisfy the `required` condition).

Here is an example code:

```
interface FormValues {
  readonly value: string;
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("rendering");

  const form: UseFormMethods<FormValues> = useForm<FormValues>({
    mode: "onChange",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: { value: "" }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    form.register({ name: "value" }, { required: true });
  }, [form, form.register]);

  const { isValid } = form.formState;
  const value = form.watch("value");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          form.setValue("value", e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      <div>IsValid: {JSON.stringify(isValid)}</div>
      <div>Errors: {JSON.stringify(form.errors)}</div>
      <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The question is sepcifically for this type of `register` use, not other types (`ref` or `Controller`).

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-fast-np7gc) is a full example.

Does someone know why this is the case, what am I missing?

Additionally, but this is less relevant - does anyone know why rendering is triggered twice for each input change?

## **EDIT**

After discussion with Dennis Vash, there was some progress on this issue, but it is still not resolved.

The docs at https://react-hook-form.com/api/#setValue actually do specify an option for triggering validation:

```
(name: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void


You can also set the shouldValidate parameter to true in order to trigger a field validation. eg: setValue('name', 'value', true)
```

At the time when I am writing this, the docs refer to version 5 of `react-form-hook`, I am actually using `6.0.0-rc.5` so the signature changed a bit to something similar to the following:

```
(name: string, value: any, { shouldValidate: boolean; shouldDirty: boolean; }) => void
```

However, in an example that I have when using `shouldValidate: true`, I get an infinite loop:

```
interface FormValues {
  readonly value: string;
}

export default function App() {
  console.log("rendering");

  const form: UseFormMethods<FormValues> = useForm<FormValues>({
    mode: "onChange",
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
    defaultValues: { value: "" }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    form.register({ name: "value" }, { required: true, minLength: 1 });
  }, [form, form.register]);

  const { isValid } = form.formState;
  const value = form.getValues("value");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          form.setValue("value", e.target.value, {
            shouldValidate: true
          });
        }}
      />
      <div>IsValid: {JSON.stringify(isValid)}</div>
      <div>Errors: {JSON.stringify(form.errors)}</div>
      <div>Value: {JSON.stringify(value)}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The loop is occurring when `isValid` is `true`, but stops when it is `false`.

You can try it out [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-driscoll-8cyv7). Entering a key will start the continuous re-rendering, and clearing the input will stop the loop...

[image]

Answer (score 23):

Referring to https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/2147

You need to set the mode to onChange or onBlur

```
const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors, isDirty, isValid }} = useForm({ mode: 'onChange' });
```

In this case, the 'isValid' will work as expected.

Comment: An old question, so I don't really have the context in my head any more. However, it seems I already was using `onChange`, as you can see in my question, and it was not working. Maybe I was still doing something wrong, or maybe it was a bug in `react-hook-form` that was subsequently fixed. Full example links are also no longer working, so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5):

The component rendered twice because of [`React.StrictMode`](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).

> Strict mode can’t automatically detect side effects for you, but it can help you spot them by making them a little more deterministic. This is done by intentionally double-invoking the following functions: ...

Also, in order to validate you need to submit the form (try pressing `enter`), if you on `onChange` mode without using a reference, you should use [`triggerValidation`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/#triggerValidation) instead.

```
export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    formState,
    watch,
    errors,
    setValue,
    handleSubmit
  }: UseFormMethods<FormValues> = useForm<FormValues>();

  useEffect(() => {
    register(
      { name: "firstName", type: "custom" },
      { required: true, min: 1, minLength: 1 }
    );
    console.log("called");
  }, [register]);

  const { isValid } = formState;
  const values = watch("firstName");

  const onSubmit = (data, e) => {
    console.log("Submit event", e);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <input
        onChange={(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
          setValue("firstName", e.target.value);
        }}
      />
      {/*<button>Click</button>*/}
      <div>IsValid: {JSON.stringify(isValid)}</div>
      <div>Errors: {JSON.stringify(errors)}</div>
      <div>Form value: {JSON.stringify(values)}</div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit old-brook-ho66h]

Comment: +1 for the `React.StrictMode`, I tried removing it and it does remove the additional render. However, regarding my main question, I tried adding the `name` to input, and it does not work. I would find it strange if it did. I am already using the name `'value'` when I make a call to `form.setValue()`, why would setting the input `name` be required in this situation. I can understand it being required when using forms with `ref`.

Comment: `isValid` is always false, and `form.errors` is always `{}`, regardless of what the input value is. Tried with your sandbox.

Comment: Well of course `isValid` is false, you didn't submit the form. Please check the edited answer, and try to press submit (`enter` key);

Comment: Check the docs at https://react-hook-form.com/api/#useForm, and note that I am using `mode: "onChange"`. The documentation states: `Validation will trigger on the change event with each input, and lead to multiple re-renders. Warning: this often comes with a significant impact on performances.`. I don't want validation only on submit, and I explicitly stated that using the configuration, or at least that is how I understand the configuration. So my question still stands: Why doesn't this work? Did I miss something else?

Comment: Yes you are missing something, "on the change event with each input" but you don't using reference, so in order for it to work you need to call validation by yourself.

Comment: ... with `triggerValidation`: https://react-hook-form.com/api/#triggerValidation

Comment: I am using version 6, so there is a `trigger` method there instead of `triggerValidation`. It seems to work, but causes other problems. If I use `watch()` it will hang the application, there is probably some infinite loop going on there. Using `const value = form.getValues("value");` to get value seems to momentarily provide the value and then revert to empty string.

Comment: I dont know what is your case, only answering the question

Comment: Anyway, all of this is very strange behavior, including the need to manually trigger validation - so `onChange` event when using `ref` will trigger validation with `mode = 'onChange'`, but `setValue` which I assumed was a manual replacement for `onChange` does not take `mode` into account...

Comment: Pretty standard behaviour for me 

Comment: Yeah, don't know about that - for me, standard behavior would be: I am using a validation mode that triggers validation on any change. I am making a change. Validation is being triggered :)

Comment: Still, while this "resolves" the original issue, now the input value is getting reset.